# undefined method `post_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0xa3ddb8c>:0xb501ae4>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form-for

I have a form which is part of a "comments" object, which is the child of a "post" object which in turn is the child of a "Category" object, I get the above error message with the following code (using simple_forms) Any advice?

```
= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| 
= f.input :comment, label: "Your Reply", input_html: {class: "form-control"} 
= f.submit
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
resources :categories do
resources :posts do
resources :comments
end
end

root 'categories#index'
end
```

Comment: Please provide your `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: post the relevant part of your config/routes.rb file

Comment: @Longshanks, please add the route in your post, not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your `comments` route under `posts`, which is nested under `categories`. With proper indentation, the error is easy to see:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories do # Everything is nested under here
    resources :posts do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
end
```

So you have a `categories_posts_comments_path`.

If you run `rake routes` in the console you should see an output of all you existing routes. If you don't want this behaviour:

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :categories do # Everything is nested under here
    resources :posts
  end
```

But beware that this will duplicate a lot of routes, so you will want to use the `only` or `except` arguments to limit the number of routes generated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to change the link to this:

```
= simple_form_for([@category, @post, @post.comments.build], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
```

and changes the routes to:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
  resources :categories do
    resources :posts
  end
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  root 'categories#index'
end
```

Comment: Thanks all for the help